# Invalid identifier while trying to multiply

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln",
    JOB_ID AS "Job_title",
    CASE COMMISSION_PCT 
        WHEN NULL THEN SALARY
        WHEN '-' THEN SALARY
        ELSE (COMISSION_PCT * SALARY) * 12
    END AS "Year income"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

I have to find year income of employee considering premium. If there is no premium i have to just ignore it. In my code i get 'ORA-00904: "COMISSION_PCT": invalid identifier' i dont know what is the reason. Dtype of COMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2) and SALARY dtype is NUMBER(8,2).

Clarification:
Specify the amount of annual income of each employee, given that the bonus is indicated as a percentage

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the error message... in your `ELSE (COMISSION_PCT` you are missing an 'M', it should be `ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT`. (Your `* 12` should probably be after the `END` but that won't error, it just might give the wrong answer. And why have you tagged this with [mysql]?)

Comment: If `COMMISSION_PCT` is a `NUMBER(2,2)`, then how can it be equal to the string `'-'`?

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Comment: @Максим - then the column is actually a number as you said, and does not have `'-'` as a value - which makes sense. Your client seems to be displaying null as a dash. So, you can just remove the handling for that, as it can't happen.

Comment: Now it doesnt display salary of people who don't have COMMISSION_PCT but just '-'

Comment: Nobody has '-', those must be null, which your code should handle. Or did you remove the `WHEN NULL THEN SALARY` line too?

Comment: No, i didnt remove it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Right, then Vvdl was right, you do need the other form of case expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off.

Try this as your `CASE` statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL THEN SALARY 
  WHEN COMMISSION_PCT = '-' THEN SALARY
  ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT * SALARY) 
END * 12 AS "Year income"
```

Comment: Both forms of [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) are valid - though the `* 12` was probably supposed to come after the `END`, as you have done. But you've left in the typo causing the error *8-)

Comment: Haha ouch. Good eyes there :). I changed the answer.

Comment: I take it back, sort of - both case expressions are valid, but you do need a searched one to handle nulls. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you have a typo; as the error says you refer to `COMISSION_PCT`, when the column is called `COMMISSION_PCT` with two Ms.

```
        ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT * SALARY) * 12
```

Then, your case expression is comparing with string literal `'-'`, but as the column is numeric no rows can have that value, so you get "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR". It appears your client is displaying null values as dashes. So you don't need to handle those.

```
    CASE COMMISSION_PCT 
        WHEN NULL THEN SALARY
        ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT * SALARY) * 12
    END AS "Year income"
```

Although that form of case expression is valid - [there are two forms](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) - in this situation you need a *searched* expression (as @Vvdl said!) because a simple one can't compare with null (as nothing is equal to, or not equal to, null):

```
    CASE
        WHEN COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL THEN SALARY
        ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT * SALARY) * 12
    END AS "Year income"
```

Though even that might not get the result you want. If `salary` is monthly then you need to multiply by 12 in both cases, or at the end:

```
    CASE
        WHEN COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL THEN SALARY
        ELSE (COMMISSION_PCT * SALARY)
    END * 12 AS "Year income"
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UtP4CcCQ)